# Pergunta ampla com resposta aceita?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, resposta-aceita, perguntas-amplas

Hoje notei que uma pergunta que respondi e foi aceita a resposta, foi marcada como "ampla". Então a questão aqui pode ser puramente filosófica.

**Como uma pergunta/dúvida que FOI SOLUCIONADA pode ser considerada como AMPLA?**

Questão: [Como ordenar os resultados de um ranking?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87055/d%C3%BAvida-para-ordenar-os-resultados-de-um-ranking)

Comment: Eu quando a li também achei ampla demais talvez por causa da forma de perguntar, mas depois vi as respostas e fiquei com a sensação contrária.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu não acho essa pergunta ampla demais, mas acho que podia ser mais clara. A sua resposta é o caminho certo, mas não sei se os exemplos são exatamente o que ele quer fazer. Porque se só houver uma entrada de tempo por usuário, ordenar as strings de tempo em ordem alfabética daria o mesmo resultado.

`TIME` é mesmo mais preciso e por isso recomendado. Mas pra essa alteração "resolver um problema", é sinal de que tem mais coisa dando errado do que o autor da pergunta disse. Talvez ele precise fazer agregação, como em `SELECT SUM(tempo) FROM bla GROUP BY usuario_id ORDER BY SUM(tempo)`. Aí sim o `TIME` é indispensável.

Então, se formos rigorosos a pergunta *não está clara o suficiente* para receber uma resposta precisa. Acho que ela está no limiar do que deve ser fechado. Se ela estivesse aberta eu provavelmente não fecharia sozinho. Decidi reabrir, embora ache que a pergunta mereça mais esclarecimentos.

---

Nada disso impede que uma outra pergunta seja ao mesmo tempo fechada como ampla e tenha uma resposta aceita. Fechar a pergunta é uma decisão de 5 pessoas, idealmente representando "a comunidade". Aceitar uma resposta é decisão exclusiva de quem fez a pergunta. Nada impede que eles discordem, e isso não contradiz nenhuma regra.

Comment: Entendo o que quer dizer, mas não justifica o fechamento (apesar de você mesmo ter dito que não fecharia sozinho), a resposta tanto foi a solução que o AP precisava que ele fez [um agradecimento e tanto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87055/como-ordenar-os-resultados-de-um-ranking#comment175430_87066). As vezes penso que a comunidade se preocupa mais com as perguntas em si, do que com o problema do AP.

Comment: Eu acho que a comunidade devia mesmo se preocupar mais com as perguntas do que com o problema específico de cada um. Perguntas claras geram respostas mais precisas e ajudam mais gente.